# Groovy wraps a java exception in its own runtime.InvokerInvocationException

Tags: unit-testing, testing, netbeans, groovy

I'm using groovy to write unit tests for my java project (I'd advise all to try it out)
One of my unit tests is testing that the tested code (in java) catches an exception of a specific type and rethrows an app exception:

java code (under test):

```
try
{
    dao.save(obj)
}
catch(DataIntegrityException dupex)
{
    ....
    throw new AppException("duplicate name");
}
```

The groovy test code mocks(proxies) the dao call using groovy's map of closures

```
[ save:
  { obj->
    ...
    throw new DataIntegrityException("duplicate"); //DataIntegrityException is a runtime exception (unchecked)
  }    
] as DAO;
```

Pretty straightforward.  However, when executing the test class, the actual exception thrown is groovy's runtime.Invoker.InvocationException which wraps the DataIntegrity exception.  Obviously, the java code knows nothing about groovy and its exceptions, so the catch block is not executed.
I'm using Netbeans 7 to actually execute the test and it just uses groovyc to compile the groovy file into a java class, and so it's just being executed as a normal JUnit test.
Anyone know how to overcome this?  couldn't find it listed in groovy's bugs, but sure seems like one.

Comment: Tried to reproduce, but can't. Does `DataIntegrityException` have a no-args constructor?

Comment: No, i just left it out for brevity.

Comment: It is an unchecked (runtime exception), so it should be new DataIntegrityViolation("message").  That isn't the problem, the exception is constructed fine, it's just wrapped by the InvocationException

Answer (score 0):

Just using this for a little more space, not yet an answer. I can get the following (minimal) setup to work:

**Dao.java**

```
public interface Dao { void save(Object obj) throws DataIntegrityException; }
```

**DataIntegrityException.java**

```
public class DataIntegrityException extends RuntimeException {
    public DataIntegrityException(String str) { super(str); }
}
```

**Test.java**

```
public class Test {
    public void doIt(Dao dao) {
        try {
            dao.save(new Object());
        } catch (DataIntegrityException e) {
            System.out.println("Caught DataIntegrityException")
        }
    }
}
```

**test_case.groovy**

```
d = [save: { throw new DataIntegrityException('duplicate') }] as Dao
new Test().doIt(d)
```

This works, i.e., it prints "Caught DataIntegrityException" to the console, using Java 6 and Groovy 1.8 (which is what I have on my machine. At the very least, the issue must lie somewhere outside of the code you've posted here.

Personally, I'd think you'd need some step-through debugging. It seems likely that the exception is being thrown from elsewhere in the code (perhaps in whatever is contained in the ellipses in your version prior to `throw new DataIntegrityException()`).

Comment: well, the problem is probably the version of groovy; netbeans' plugin uses groovy 1.6.4 (and unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a simple way to just incorporate the newest groovy jar--if i'm wrong somebody please correct me).  I am curious though--what if you remove the throws DataIntegrityException declaration from your DAO save?  For a variety of reasons I can't do that in my case, but perhaps groovy uses reflection to figure out that it should unwrap its exception?  It should certainly work without the throws clause.

Comment: anyways, your code is essentially EXACTLY what I'm testing (except for the throws declaration on DAO.save) and of course the groovy version differences

Comment: @igaz: I tried removing the explicit throws declaration, but the result is the same. The Groovy version does seem to be a likely candidate. Let me look into that.

Comment: @igaz: Maybe [these instructions](http://www.codesofmylife.com/?p=192) help getting a new version of Groovy in Netbeans? You might also try varying your mocking method to leverage either an `Expando` class or closure coercion, in case the behavior is tied to map coercion. I'll put some examples.

Comment: Also, what version of Netbeans are you working with? I was under the impression that the plugin was deprecated in favor of native IDE support ([source](http://groovy.codehaus.org/NetBeans+Plugin)).